# Select incremented integer

Tags: mysql, integer

I want to know if it's possible to select incremented integer from mysql table? and if it does possible, how can I achieve that?

My case is, I have a bunch of data and I need to do `INSERT INTO newtable ... SELECT somefield FROM sometable`. However, there is one field on `newtable` called `counter` that I need it in incremented integer, eg:

```
row #1: counter=1
row #2: counter=2
row #3: counter=3
row #4: counter=4
row #5: counter=5
row #6: counter=6
... and so on...
```

I can do this using simple php script, but I want to try to do it all from mysql query. So, can you guys tell me if it's possible?

Comment: Does default Auto Increment not suiting you?

Comment: Auto increment is not solution for my problem

Comment: @Nazariy Auto increment relies on loading the data into a table. There are situations where an arbitrary index needs to be added to some data and the solution suggested below by Chandu is exactly what is required. There are a number of cases where variables within queries enable the developer to solve a problem elegantly. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO newTable(someField, counter)
SELECT a.someField, (@rank:=@rank+1) AS counter
  FROM sometable a INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT @rank :=0) b
```

Comment: Btw, can you tell me, what is this '@' character? maybe link to it's documentation?