# How does Github make issues for each repo start from id=1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I really like how Github starts the ids for issues from 1 for each repo.

How do you model that info using ActiveRecord?

I want to support the following URL scheme `/profile/:username/posts/:post_id`

I'd like for posts for each user to start at 1 and then increment from there.

Answer (score 2):

Rails doesn't do this easily, but you can use composite keys to accomplish this, where the key is (repo id, issue id). [This gem](https://github.com/drnic/composite_primary_keys) will add support for them to Rails 3. You would need a generator to generate incrementing IDs per repo.

If you don't want to go full-on compound keys, you can fake it in your code. You just want something like `@repo.issues.find(params[:issue_id])`, where issues contains both a `repo_id` and `issue_id` key, in addition to the normal incrementing PK.

Comment: Is the best way to increment the issue_id to add a `before_create` and check for the max issue_id for a repo?

Comment: No, because that's subject to collisions. You should use an atomic increment-and-select, as is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073884/select-incremented-integer

Answer (score 1):

You should instead let each post have a unique global id. In threads or in the context of a user, numbering can start at 1 as a convenience -- that is, it will not be a number stored in the database, but when you request `/users/someuser/posts/1` it will actually look up the first post for that user of all of their posts ordered by ascending creation date, regardless of what the post ID actually is.

Example: user requested `/users/someuser/posts/3`, SQL might be something like `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username = :username ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2`

Comment: Neat idea. How do you prevent posts from shifting their ids down if an earlier post is deleted?

Comment: Add a 'deleted' flag to posts and do soft deletes instead of actual deletes (probably the best idea for moderation, anyways.)